# Trying to learn mysqli, none of my statements are actually returning results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Exactly what it sounds like, none of my retrieval statements retrieve the data as it should. This is peculiar, as if I copy the exact query and put it into phpMyAdmin and run it there, it returns results as it should.

Insertion statements and the like work, such as this:

```
    // On first connect to database, create a user to hold data for users not logged in
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) VALUES (1, 'anonymous', 'anonymous', '" . password_hash("...", PASSWORD_BCRYPT) . "')");
    }
```

And the user is entered as intended.

But if I run a statement such as this:

```
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = $email");
    $row = $result->fetch();
```

I get the following error: "**Fatal error:** Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object"

Running the exact same statement in phpMyAdmin returns the row as intended.

It only works in one area, however:

```
            if ($result = $db->query("SELECT username, wins, losses FROM users ORDER BY wins DESC LIMIT 10")) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["wins"] . "</td> <td>" . $row["losses"] . "</td></tr>\n";
                }
            }
```

Which returns the intended results. I don't know why, though.

I'm not sure if the structure of my files matters, I have a config.php file that I require in and it has the connection information. The rest is in my index.php file.

Here's config.php:

```
<?php
    $db_host = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $db_user = "...";
    $db_pass = "...";
    $db_database = "hangman";

    $db = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_database);

    if ($db->connect_error) {
        echo "Could not connect to database.";
        exit;
    }
    // On first connect to database, create a user to hold data for users not logged in
    $result = $db->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = 1");
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        $db->query("INSERT INTO users (id, username, email, password) VALUES (1, 'anonymous', 'anonymous', '" . password_hash("...", PASSWORD_BCRYPT) . "')");
    }
?>
```

I can include more of my PHP, please just say what, this is just driving me crazy.

Comment: do you even connect to the db?

Comment: [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Changed to `fetch_assoc()` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, while your input is from  a database, you still should never trust any data you didn't type yourself.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = $email");
$row = $result->fetch();
```

This has a Syntax Error: `$email` requires quotes, as it is a string.

Are you really sure you're connecting to `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]`?
You should really connect to just `localhost` instead...

A tip for testing your queries is to wrap it in `if` blocks, because if it fails, `FALSE` is returned instead of an object. You can't call `false->fetch()`.

```
if ($result = $db->query($sql)) {
    //do stuff, fetch data, etc.
} else {
    if (DEBUG) { // define('DEBUG', 1);
        trigger_error("Query Failed; Fix it: " . htmlspecialchars($sql));
    } else {
        header("Location: /oops.php");
    }
}
```

Also, use a [`prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for this. In fact, use a prepare for everything that inserts data, or includes user input, period. And define it **before** any loops.

```
if ($x = $db->prepare("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = ?")) {
    $x->bind_param("s", $email);
    $x->execute();
    $x->bind_result($id, $user, $pass);
    $x->fetch();
}
```

Fetch doesn't do exactly what you are used to. It fetches data after a query has been executed. `fetch_assoc` will fetch an associative array from a result object.

In addition, querying your database for `users.id = 1` every single time anyone loads a page is not a good idea. Stick that in the setup script. And make the anonymous user have an impossible password (aka instead of `$2y$13$<hash>` it would be `Nope, not happenin'` or something).

Also, you are echoing into HTML directly from the database. If you dont sanitize, I could create a username like `<script src=""></script>` and have a lot of fun with the latest exploits. Sanitize~

**UPDATE**: After reading your code, I found your issue.

```
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT wins FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT losses FROM users WHERE id = ?");
$stmt1->bind_param($_SESSION["id"]);
$stmt2->bind_param($_SESSION["id"]);
$stmt1->execute();
$stmt2->execute();
$row1 = $stmt1->fetch();
$row2 = $stmt2->fetch();
```

There's three issues here<sup>1</sup>.

First issue is that ***you can only have one prepare call on a given connection at a time***. I'm fairly certain this is because it's a blocking API call. Correct me if I'm wrong.

The second is that ***you do not specify a type for the `bind_param` call***. You must assign a type to anything you specify here. `s` = string, `i` = integer.

The third is that ***you do not bind any result variables here at all***. You **must** bind variables when using a prepared query. This is a fix for this instance:

```
if ($query = $db->prepare("SELECT wins, losses FROM users WHERE id = ?")) {
    $query->bind_param("s", $_SESSION["id"]);
    $query->execute();
    $query->bind_result($wins, $losses);
    if (!$query->fetch()) { // fetch one row from database.
        logout(); // or equiv.
    }
} else {
    if (DEBUG) {
        echo "Malformed SQL or In-use thread. SQL: <sql here>";
    } else {
        header("Location: /oops.php");
    }
}
```

<sup>1. Or 4 if you count doing this with multiple queries.</sup>

Comment: My problem is that it should return values for the queries. It's not, and an if statement won't change that. Also, I use prepare statements throughout, but I've been told if it's with static, literal data there's no point in having it as a prepare statement.

Comment: `fetch_assoc` still messes up.

Comment: @user212541 prepares should be used anywhere you insert unsafe data. also judging my your previous question, this is an issue with your MySQL install or PHP itself. You are getting errors from perfectly good code. Also, what `fetch_assoc`? I never mentioned it :). Also, an important note is to **check the value that fetch returns**. `NULL` = no data, `FALSE` = Error, `TRUE` = a row returned.

Comment: I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my installs. I used PHP's soon to be deprecated mysql functions and it worked perfectly, but I wanted to reimplement it in mysqli for future proofing it. But it won't seem to work now.

Comment: I really think I must have some really stupid mistake. Could you give my code a quick lookover? http://cl.ly/3s0r0u0k0L1L

Comment: @user212541 It was an error prior to what you linked. Updated~

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure what exactly the error is.

No wonder. You didn't ask for this.
You have to **always** check for the errors when running a query

```
$sql = "SELECT wins, losses FROM users WHERE id = 1";
$res = $db->query($sql) or trigger_error($db->error." [$sql]");
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: But the manual doesn't say anything about having to use that trigger_error function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @user212541 you're not *required* to, but you should. Would you jump off a bridge just because no one explicitly told you not to?

Comment: That's rather irrelevant. He says you have to always check, nowhere in the PHP Manual does it say that is true, nor is that the source of my problem. If I include that, it just skips by it, when it should be catching the entries.

Answer (score 1):

Your query has a syntax error which is going to cause the query to fail which means $result will not be a result object.  The first query will fail because you aren't putting quotes around the email:

```
SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = $email
```

should be:

```
SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = '$email'
```

After your query you should put something like below:

```
if ($result->errno!=0){
    echo $result->error;
    exit(0)
}
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
//etc.
```

Comment: But that detects if there is an error. There shouldn't be an error in this case, so that should only come up if I'm messing something up, right?

Comment: right, in this case, I think your queries may have little errors, for example the one I give above.

Comment: While this is a valid answer for the question and I'm upvoting it, it turns out the OP actually had a lot more than just the Syntax Error. He linked his project in a comment earlier.

Answer (score 0):

@hiroto is correct.
If there is no result, then there can be no object, and that is why you are getting a fatal error of calling a method on a non-object.  There is a problem with the SQL query, as he mentioned, and email needs to be quoted as it is a string.  MySQL will fail with an error otherwise.

Also, mysqli result object does not have a method of fetch(), which is why he suggested fetch_assoc();

To get the result then, you'll need to quote the email so that you get a result object, and when accessing the data either do a loop:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    print_r($row);
}
```

or pull the data directly by key:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE email = '$email'");
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['username'];
```